# How to add conditional check to render button depending on two input fields?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a login screen where there is name field and number field below is a button 'Continue' which should turn pink only when both the fields are not empty but now whenever I type in the first field itself the button is turning pink, I have added checks as required as follows:

```
{mobile.length <= 10 && firstName === '' ? (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#C0C0C0',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 50,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    marginTop: '20%',
                  }}
                  disabled={true}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: 'white',

                      fontSize: 18,
                    }}>
                    Continue
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              ) : continueresploading == true ? (
                <ActivityIndicator
                  size="large"
                  color="#FE017E"
                  style={{marginTop: '20%'}}
                />
              ) : (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  style={{
                    backgroundColor: '#FF1493',
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 50,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                    marginTop: '20%',
                  }}
                  onPress={() => onHandlePress()}>
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      color: 'white',

                      fontSize: 18,
                    }}>
                    Continue
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              )}
```

However this is not working as per my expectation, maybe there is something that I have missed, if anyone could point that out to me it would be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
const [btnClassName, setBtnClassName] = useState('first-style');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

const onChangeHandler = (e) =>{
    const name = e.currentTarget.name;
    const value = e.currentTarget.value;

    if(name === 'email'){
        setEmail(value);            
    }
    else if(name === 'password'){
        setPassword(value)
    }

}

useEffect(()=>{
    if (email !== '' && password !== ''){ 
        setBtnClassName('second-style')
    }
    else {
        setBtnClassName('first-style')
    }

}, [email, password])

return (
    <input type="password" name='password' onChange = {(e) =>onChangeHandler(e)} />

    <input type="email" name='email' onChange = {(e) =>onChangeHandler(e)}/>

    <button className = {btnClassName} onClick={(e)=> onClickHandler(e)}>Click</button>
)
```

I'm defining a state named `btnClassName` which initially has the value of `('first-style')` and upon each change on `email` and `password`, I check if both of them are `!== ''`, then I change the state to `('second-style')`.

You should handle it this way. I have never tried react-native, but I'm sure this should work there too.
And I didn't test it, there might be some bugs or even typos, cause I'm typing on my phone.

Comment: + avoid using inline styles, your code gets messy and unreadable.